# SharePoint:FormField force render as select menu?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm editing a custom NewForm.aspx page using SPD in SP2010. What I am trying to do is to get SharePoint to render a particular field with about 300 items as a select menu. SP insists on rendering the field as that typeahead lookup control, which for my situation will not work. I want it to render the field just the way it does when there are only a few items in the list; a good ol' HTML select menu.

My googling and binging have not been successful. There is no apparent "renderAs" argument I can set on the SharePoint:FormField control.

I tried asking a smiliar question over at sharepoint.stackexchange.com without much success, so apologies in advance if it's bad form to ask again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I shall answer my own question, rude as that may be. I found that if I created a new NewForm.aspx page (named slightly differntly) and added the data-bound dropdown control to it manually, it stayed that way as desired. Attempts to re-use the default NewForm.aspx page were in vain.